# JSF passing arguments to method in EL

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

Here is the html code for that:

```
<h:form>
        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{worldCupData.worldCup}"
            converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter">
            <f:selectItems value="#{worldCupData.worldCups}" var="worldCup"
                itemValue="#{worldCup}"
                itemLabel="#{worldCup.year}, #{worldCup.host}"></f:selectItems>
        </h:selectOneMenu>
        <p></p>
        <h:commandButton id="selectCupButton" value="Submit" action="#{countryData.getCountries(worldCup.year)}">
        </h:commandButton>
    </h:form>
```

I have a method in my `CountryData` class called `getCountries(String year)` that should be called when the submit button is pressed. I am trying to pass the `#{worldCup.year}` value to the method.

Is this how methods are referenced in EL for JSF? Am I doing this right?

Comment: Indeed, it is the exact syntax but what are you asking for especially ? Are you getting errors doing so ?

Comment: I was getting errors before, but it was for a different reason. It's working fine now. With this code.

Comment: so there is no question ?